# Peewee 'Connection already open' in url_value_preprocessor with Flask

Tags: python, flask, peewee

What I am trying to do is check the subdomain value passed to the route methods just like explained [here](http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/blueprints.html#using-a-dynamic-subdomain)

Whenever I access the `panel` blueprint I receive this error: `peewee.OperationalError: Connection already open`

This is how I initialize the database in my main app file.

```
flask_db = FlaskDB(app)
database = flask_db.database
```

The problematic code seems to be

```
@panel.url_value_preprocessor
def check_client_and_user(endpoint, values):
    client = Client.get(Client.subdomain == values.pop('client'))
```

The full source code can be found on [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/MNApps/Server/tree/master/app)

`__init__.py` is the main app file. `panel/__init__.py` has the problematic code. This is the full traceback I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marten/Projects/Comp/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/marten/Projects/Comp/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/marten/Projects/Comp/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/marten/Projects/Comp/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/marten/Projects/Comp/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/marten/Projects/Comp/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/marten/Projects/Comp/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/marten/Projects/Comp/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/marten/Projects/Comp/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1610, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.preprocess_request()
  File "/home/marten/Projects/Comp/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1831, in preprocess_request
    rv = func()
  File "/home/marten/Projects/Comp/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/playhouse/flask_utils.py", line 171, in connect_db
    self.database.connect()
  File "/home/marten/Projects/Comp/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3679, in connect
    raise OperationalError('Connection already open')
peewee.OperationalError: Connection already open
```

I don't know where the extra connection is coming from. It seems like it is being generated by the Client.select() query.

---

**Edit**:
This code here

```
def get_or_404(client):
    app.logger.debug(database.get_tables())
    cli = Client.select().where(Client.subdomain == client)
```

Generates this response

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG in models [/home/marten/Projects/Comp/server/app/panel/models.py:14]:
['client', 'role', 'user', 'userroles']
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2017 14:57:31] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marten/Projects/Comp/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/marten/Projects/Comp/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/marten/Projects/Comp/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/marten/Projects/Comp/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/marten/Projects/Comp/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/marten/Projects/Comp/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/marten/Projects/Comp/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/marten/Projects/Comp/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/marten/Projects/Comp/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1610, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.preprocess_request()
  File "/home/marten/Projects/Comp/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1831, in preprocess_request
    rv = func()
  File "/home/marten/Projects/Comp/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/playhouse/flask_utils.py", line 171, in connect_db
    self.database.connect()
  File "/home/marten/Projects/Comp/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3679, in connect
    raise OperationalError('Connection already open')
peewee.OperationalError: Connection already open
```

As you can see the database is actually connected, and the client table is available.

---

**Edit 2**: 
Well, I just found that apparently just `database.get_tables()` will cause this error. However, that code does fetch all tables from the database...

Does `url_value_preprocessor` run before the database is initialized? That would be strange since I import the object calling this decorator after initializing the database.